# Write Permission Error

Tags: permissions, transmission

I have `transmission-deamon` running and it's giving me the error `Permission Denied: /mnt/RyNet/Downloads/the-torrent/some-file.ext`

So it cannot write files to the download directory:

```
ryguy@MPU /mnt/RyNet $ id debian-transmission
uid=120(debian-transmission) gid=132(debian-transmission) groups=132(debian-transmission),117(sambashare)
ryguy@MPU /mnt/RyNet $ ps aux | grep transmis
120      16184  0.2  0.3  57724 12644 ?        Ssl  22:17   0:11 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --config-dir /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info
ryguy@MPU /mnt/RyNet $ ls -alh
total 100K
drwxrwx--- 16 root  sambashare 4.0K Apr 15 21:36 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  root       4.0K Dec  4 08:20 ..
drwxrwxrwx  4 root  sambashare 4.0K Apr 20 05:30 Downloads
```

But, I have the download directory permissions set to `777`, owned by group `sambashare`.
The `transmission-deamon` is running as `debian-transmission` user/group and the `debian-transmission` user is in group `sambashare`.

Even stranger, when I set the `debian-transmission` user's shell to `/bin/bash` and login via `su`, I can easily issue commands such as `touch /mnt/RyNet/Downloads/testfile` with no errors and it creates the `testfile` just fine.

So, why can't `transmission-deamon` write files to the download directory?

Answer (score 1):

Aha! The `transmission-deamon` was in group `sambashare` but was not it's main group.

Issuing `sudo usermod -g sambashare debian-transmission` solved my problem.